# git fetch : output that there was an update

Tags: git, version-control, git-fetch

The expected behaviour for fetch in case of an update is the following (imho):

```
$ git fetch -p
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From AAA
   a061e40..2058467  develop    -> origin/develop
```

This works for me in project A. Fetching from the same git host, same local system, different project (say, project B), `git fetch` gives me no output. I think it has changed at some point in time but I cannot make out what the cause was.

Project B, `git fetch` output:

```
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
$ git fetch -pv
From BBB
 = [up to date]      develop                       -> origin/develop
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Project A config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = AAA
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop

$ git branch -vv
* develop    a061e40 [origin/develop: behind 1]
```

Project B config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = BBB
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop

$ git branch -vv
* develop                       7d1afd6 [origin/develop: behind 2]
```

How can I change the behavior of `git fetch` in project B back to how it behaves in project A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your current develop branch commit id with `.git\refs\remotes\origin\develop`.

If the two commits are the same, that means your local develop branch is really up to date.

If the two commits are different, you can use `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` to check if `develop` and `origin/develop` are point the same commit id. Or you can use `git branch -D develop` and `git checkout develop`, then make changes on remote repo, and do `git fetch` again.

Comment: Sry to come back so late, it got a bit pushed back by priorities. Deleting the local `develop` branch and checking it out again fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestion! I still don't know what the problem was, though.

Comment: If it can work normally now, it’s mainly caused you fetched from remote by accident before.

Comment: "fetched by accident"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: It's possible that before you use `git fetch -p` and show `up to date`, that it had fetched locally.